# returning different values in an NSubstitute mock method with an out parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

Given a method with which to mock...

```
public bool TryReceive(out T message, TimeSpan millisecondsToWait)
```

- I wish to set different messages on the first two calls, and return
  true.
- Subsequent calls return false.

I have tried a few variations, and in either case, the **lambda expression is executed once**, and never again. NSubstitute seems to be **caching the first return value**, and using the same value over and over.

I have tried this...

```
TCR @out;
var container = new AutoSubstitute();
var mb = container.Resolve<IMessageBuffer<TCR>>();
mb.TryReceive(out @out, Arg.Any<TimeSpan>()).Returns(
            _ => { _[0] = buy; return true; },
            _ => { _[0] = sell; return true; },
            _ => { _[0] = null; return false; });
```

and I have tried this:

```
        bool? bs = true;
        TCR @out;
        var container = new AutoSubstitute();
        var mb = container.Resolve<IMessageBuffer<TCR>>();
        mb.TryReceive(out @out, Arg.Any<TimeSpan>()).Returns(
            _ =>
            {
                if (bs == true)
                {
                    _[0] = buy;
                    bs = false;
                    return true;
                }
                if (bs == false)
                {
                    _[0] = sell;
                    bs = null;
                    return true;
                }
                _[0] = null;
                return false;
            });
```

The only option I can think of is to provide a complete substitute implementation of the buffer for test purposes. My feeling is that given this [documentation](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/setting-out-and-ref-arguments/), it should be possible.

**edit**

I have been unable to get this working using NSubstitute, however if I provide a mock implementation of the `IMessageBuffer<TCR>` using

```
// mock buffer will return the necessary values by maintaining
// the relevant state internally.
container.Provide<IMessageBuffer<TCR>>(new MockBuffer());
```

it works correctly, so it's not a lifetimescope issue. Somehow NSubstitute seems to be calling the mocked out method only the first time, and reusing the value (or operating in such a way that it *seems* to reuse the value) - very strange.

Comment: sorry, I am using AutoContainer, which provides Subsitute.For, I have added that code to the question. AutoContainer just provides the Substitute.For, and keeps the result in the container so that the same substitute is resolved each time a dependency is needed.

Comment: You may add some brakpoints at every anonymous code-block to check which one is actually called.

Comment: I have, the weird thing is that lambda is called once, and once only. after that, the same result is supplied every time.

Comment: And when you use the second appraoch shown above it works?

Comment: no, I have started digging around, and I think I have some lifetimescope issues. I have a feeling the problem is more complex than an issue with NSubstitute

Comment: Obviously you´re calling `TryRecieve` only once. Of course you have to call it three times (or more often).Show where and how you call the method which you want to mock.

Comment: I am calling it in a loop, many times. I seem to just get the same value every time. If I put a breakpoint on the lambda it stops once, but each time TryReceive returns it sets the same result.

Comment: The lambda is only ever called once, regardless of how many times TryReceive is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSubstitute struggles a bit with `out` and `ref` parameters.

The problem is that when we stub:

```
mb.TryReceive(out @out, Arg.Any<TimeSpan>()).Returns(...)
```

this will only execute when `@out` is the original value. This value will change the first time it is called, so the `Returns` lambda won't execute again (NSub thinks it is a different, non-matching call).

The easiest way to work-around this is to switch to `ReturnsForAnyArgs(...)`:

```
mb.TryReceive(out @out, Arg.Any<TimeSpan>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(action0, action1, action2);
```

This will work for all `TryReceive` calls, regardless of the parameter values, so the lambda should always execute. The downside of this is that if you want this to only run for specific values of the second argument then you'll have to put that logic inside the lambda (rather than using an argument matcher).